# Different hashes with same input values

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptojs

I'm building a api and I'm having trouble generating a hash with CryptoJs in the client-side interface

My js function does this:

```
console.log(" username: '" + $rootScope.username + "'");
console.log("timestamp: '" + timestamp + "'");  
console.log("  request: '" + req + "'");
console.log("  entropy: '" + "dragonsahead" + "'");
console.log(" password: '" + $rootScope.password + "'");
var message = $rootScope.username+timestamp+req+"dragonsahead";
console.log("  message: '" + message +"'");
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message, $rootScope.password).toString();
console.log("     HASH: '" + hash + "'");
return hash;
```

`$rootScope.username` and `$rootScope.password` are user inputs;

JS Log:

```
 username: 'admin' 
timestamp: '1394643128.478' 
  request: '/login' 
  entropy: 'dragonsahead' 
 password: 'e1a47a0407d876c8187b1e984a6813abde8160af' 
  message: 'admin1394643128.478/logindragonsahead' 
     HASH: '5061875265279c7378c95c9536feade1c610492d'
```

I could see in the server-side logs that the hashes did not match.
PHP server Log:

```
2014-03-12 16:52:08 - INFO -->  username: 'admin' 
2014-03-12 16:52:08 - INFO --> timestamp: '1394643128.478' 
2014-03-12 16:52:08 - INFO -->   request: '/login' 
2014-03-12 16:52:08 - INFO -->   entropy: 'dragonsahead' 
2014-03-12 16:52:08 - INFO -->  password: 'e1a47a0407d876c8187b1e984a6813abde8160af' 
2014-03-12 16:52:08 - INFO -->   message: 'admin1394643128.478/logindragonsahead' 
2014-03-12 16:52:08 - INFO -->      HASH: '4c34a29aa05059d5016bd74796407de3d2e5428c' 
2014-03-12 16:52:08 - INFO -->CLIENTOKEN: '5061875265279c7378c95c9536feade1c610492d'
```

After this I checked i [this site](http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.htm) and the hash built by the server was the right one.
So, I decided lo load CryptoJS to a blank page (google, for example) and see what could happen:

```
> var jq = document.createElement('script');
> jq.src = "https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js";
> document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
<script src=​"https:​/​/​crypto-js.googlecode.com/​svn/​tags/​3.1.2/​build/​rollups/​hmac-sha1.js">​</script>​
>var test = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("admin1394643128.478/logindragonsahead",'e1a47a0407d876c8187b1e984a6813abde8160af')
undefined
>test.toString()
"4c34a29aa05059d5016bd74796407de3d2e5428c"
```

As CryptoJS returned the right hash, It can only be that I am messing up with my javascript vars. I don't know what could possibly be messing up my variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that I was storing the password in a angularjs's "$rootScope".

I need to do `$rootScope.password.tostring()` instead of `$rootScope.password`;

Solved.